# This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path

Tags: git, github

Please help me understand what the below error message means and how to comply with its request.

I want to copy an existing local git repo; then push that copy to a newly created remote.

But I get the following error:

> This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/pre-push.

The code I used immediately prior to getting this message is:

```bash
# create new git repo at https://github.com/username/foo-bar.git
cp -r OldProject/ NewProject/
cd NewProject/
git remote remove origin # Remove prior origin from copy operation
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/foo-bar.git
git add -A
git commit -m "first commit"
git push -u origin master
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Please help me understand what the above error message means and how to comply with its request.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message says? I mean `remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/pre-push.`

Comment: @Polygnome: No. Because I have no idea what that means. Perhaps I should have made that clearer in my question. Can you please help me understand what the error message means and how to do that?

Comment: @Polygnome: Oh. It's a file. That was the key word missing from my understanding. Thanks.

Comment: You probably shouldn't just delete the file, you might lose something stored in git lfs. You probably want to [install it](https://git-lfs.github.com/) instead.

Comment: If anyone cares to take a stab at explaining what the error message means, I would be very appreciative and inclined to accept the answer.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

> This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path

LFS is "Large File Storage" an extension for git that keeps large files outside of the actual repository so it doesn't become slow. When the error says "not found on your path" it means git was looking for a program that you don't have installed. You can install it using the instructions on https://git-lfs.github.com/.

A hook, by the way, is a bit of code git runs when you do some action. They are stored in the repository, in the hidden directory `.git/hooks`.

Comment: I installed it using the instructions at https://git-lfs.github.com/ and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Installed it, and it worked like a charm (after restarting Console)

Comment: I installed it using the link provided above and still seeing the same error. So, I did as the error stated and deleted the `.git/hooks/pre-push` and finally, it worked.

Comment: Installed it via home-brew as described at https://git-lfs.github.com. Works. thanks!

Comment: Should we use Git LFS if we do not have to? It's telling me an empty Unity project "uses Git LFS" and I am not sure how it came to this decision (or what made this decision).

Comment: @Anwarvic Where would `.git/hooks/pre-push` be in order to `rm .git/hooks/pre-push`?

Comment: I had to delete `.git/hooks/pre-push-sample` too.

Answer (score 22):

> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio
> samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git,
> while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or
> GitHub Enterprise.

Probably the easiest thing is just to install [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) by running:

```
brew install git-lfs
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and solved it by deleting .git/hooks/pre-push

Comment: Do not do this if you want to keep git lfs. Doing this remove a hook needed by git lfs. Fix the problem instead by putting lfs in your path.

Comment: @Nick it's right, this isn't a solution for this problem

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have solved it for people who may be using SourceTree.
For me, since I installed SourceTree before git on a fresh machine, SourceTree was using an embedded version of git, which didn't have git lfs installed I guess.

So I went to Tools > Options > Git, and at the bottom I noticed some settings to choose which version of git that Sourcetree uses.:
[Tools > Options > Git version settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INv0d.png)

So I had previously had it on "Embedded", but I changed it to System, and things have been good so far.

While this may be fairly obvious to most, I think I will mention it anyways:
This will only work if you have git and lfs installed on your system from https://git-scm.com/. The git installer has an option to install git-lfs at some point during installation.

EDIT: So after this, the problems still persisted, but then I remembered that this issue only started after I had installed a new M.2 NVME drive and loaded my repo onto it.

So I guess if you run git lfs from a drive that is slower than the drive that is slower than the repo, Sourcetree will think that you don't have git lfs configured.
So I uninstalled Git and LFS, and reinstalled them on my fastest drive, the M.2 NVME drive, and I haven't had any issues since.

Comment: Let me repeat the thing that wasn't at all obvious: "This will only work if you have git and lfs installed on your system from https://git-scm.com/. " So do NOT install git-lfs separately, it just doesn't work. This was the case at least on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

People in this comment thread are talking about deleting the pre-push hook, but this alone will not fix the issue. You have to run

```
git lfs install
```

in order for the git lfs to be correctly added to the hook

Answer (score 1):

For me (Ubuntu 22.04), running:

```
sudo apt install git-lfs
```

solved the issue. After that, I just run:

```
git push --set-upstream origin branch_name
```

Hope, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Look out if the branch you have checked out contains file `.gitattributes` and therein you find something like `<any file pattern> filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text`.

That makes Sourcetree getting aware of Git-LFS being used. If it was newly added with a branch and it's not on master yet, notice that Sourcetree will bring up the hint only when opened if a branch where that exists is already checked out.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `git lfs install` it configures all the repositories to use git lfs. This is what you probably don't want. Instead, you can configure git lfs to use for specific repositories only.

```bash
❯ git lfs uninstall
Hooks for this repository have been removed.
Global Git LFS configuration has been removed.
```

```bash
<cd to the repo, which uses lfs>
git lfs install --local
```

This will enable git lfs only for particular repository.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error in VSCode. git lfs showed in the terminal path so somehow the VSCode path got corrupted. I restarted VSCode and it worked.