# Reduce repository size | error: failed to push some refs to [remote]

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am stuck for 2 days trying to find a way to clean up my remote `gitlab` repo. I mistakenly push local repo after adding my data folder, which I forgot to include in the git-ignore. Since then, I cannot push any more, as the remote grows to `9.8GB`, so I kept getting exceeded storage error.

I then completely removed the data folder fom my git-tracked repo. The resulting local repo is now about `12M` size (python scripts and jupyter notebooks) only. Despite this clean-up, yet I cannot push to remove.

I followed the procedure outlined [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html).

1. Cloned a fresh copy of my repository from using `--bare` and `--mirror` options:

```
$ git clone --bare --mirror my-repo.git
```

2. And changed to cloned repo:

```
$ cd my-repo.git
```

3. Purge all files larger than 10M:

```
$ git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
Processed 1306 blob sizes
Parsed 53 commits
New history written in 0.06 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
Enumerating objects: 1195, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1195/1195), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (910/910), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1195/1195), done.
Reusing bitmaps: 43, done.
Building bitmaps: 100% (51/51), done.
Total 1195 (delta 237), reused 1095 (delta 217), pack-reused 0
Completely finished after 6.89 seconds.
```

4. Then delete this origin remote, and set the URL to my repository:

```
$ git remote remove origin
Note: A branch outside the refs/remotes/ hierarchy was not removed;
to delete it, use:
  git branch -d master
$ git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/my-repo.git
```

5. Now I need to force push my changes to overwrite all branches on GitLab:

```
$ git push origin --force 'refs/heads/*'
Username for 'https://gitlab.com': xxx@gmail.com
Password for 'https://xxx@gmail.com@gitlab.com': 
Enumerating objects: 1195, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1195/1195), 275.18 MiB | 18.29 MiB/s, done.
Total 1195 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1195
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (237/237), done.
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.
To https://gitlab.com/my-repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/my-repo.git'
```

This step failed! Unfortunately, all answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848741/this-repository-is-configured-for-git-lfs-but-git-lfs-was-not-found-on-your-pa) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69737396/error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-path) didn't help solve the problem.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

> remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.

That's your answer, right there.  You commanded GitLab to update the name `master`.  GitLab said: "No.  *You* are not allowed."

Find out who *is* allowed and have them do it, or change the set of people who are allowed, or authenticate as a person who is allowed.  Those are your options.

Answer (score 0):

A silly suggestion have you tried changing remote on gitLab and removing the folder to reduce the size of the repo?
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/3518